# React keeps emptying the array on each click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

Creating a React app where the user chooses 2 movies out of 5 options and if the movies are the same it returns Success. I attempted to store the choices made in state and then compare them, it returns the Success correctly but when a second movie is clicked after the first one it says the choices array is empty again.

So if I click movie1 and then click movie2 and then click movie1 a second time it will say success as if its storing each movie clicked in its own separate array

I've tried many variations but this is the general code I have:

```
const [userChoices, setUserChoices] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {
    if (userChoices.length === 2) {
        console.log(userChoices)

        if (userChoices[0] === userChoices[1]) {
            console.log('W');
        } else {
            console.log('L');
        }
    }
}, [userChoices]);


const handleObjectSelect = (selectedObject) => {
    // Checks if movie choices were a match
    setUserChoices((prevChoices) => {
        const updatedChoices = [...prevChoices, selectedObject];
    });

    
};

return <div className="content-card" onClick={() => handleObjectSelect(movie?.title)}>
    <img className="movie-poster img-fluid" src={`${img500x500}/${movie?.poster_path}`} />
    <div className="movie-title">{movie?.title}</div>
    <div className="movie-info">
        <span>{movie?.release_date}</span>
        <span><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar} />{movie?.vote_average}</span>
    </div>
</div>;
```

I also tried storing the choices in a regular array and a regular variable but the same problem persists, I'm new to react and would appreciate any help thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it!
You forgot to return state in your function.

```
setUserChoices((prevChoices) => {
        const updatedChoices = [...prevChoices, selectedObject];
        return updatedChoices;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! it's still giving me the same answer, when I click movie1,movie2,movie3 and then repeat that order it prints [movie1,movie1] [movie2,movie2] and [movie3,movie3] to the console, as if its storing each movie clicked in its own separate array

Answer (score 0):

You should return the value when you set it:

```
const handleObjectSelect = (selectedObject) => {
 // Checks if movie choices were a match
 setUserChoices((prevChoices) => {
    const updatedChoices = [...prevChoices, selectedObject];
    return updatedChoices; //This line should be added.
 });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

as others have pointed out, you just have a small syntax error, the short hand syntax would look like this:

```
setUserChoices((prevChoices) =>  [...prevChoices, selectedObject]);
```

One small suggestion is that you probably don't need an array or even `useEffect` to achieve this. If you think about it, just a simple string is good enough. You set the string to be empty initially, then, before you set it to a new string, compare it to the old string first and see if they match!

```
const handleObjectSelect = (selectedObject) => {
 if (selectedObject === userChoice) {
   // Success case
 }  else {
   setUserChoice(selectedObject);
 {
};
```

My last tip would be to look into how to setup and use Typescript. I know it's gonna be quite challenging learning Typescript but it will help you catch almost 99% of these syntax issues. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So I want the user to only make 2 choices and if they dont match I will generate new movies to be chosen, I tried this `
if (userChoices.length) {
            if (selectedObject === userChoices) {
                // Success case
                console.log('W');
            } else {
                console.log('L');
            }
        } else {
            setUserChoices(selectedObject);
        }` 
but again, it never logs 'L'  if different movies are chosen.